# iOS Static Frameworks Inter Dependencies

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, dependencies, static-libraries

I'm having a little dilemma with how to organize my project.

I had a single framework I was distributing to clients. I had no problems up to now since dependencies were simple. I'm using XCode Cocoa Touch Framework but as "Static Library" in match-o type to build my frameworks.

Now i need to distribute multiple frameworks to multiple clients, all using the same Core code, which I don't want to expose to my clients. How do I do this?

Say I have the following Frameworks:

```
FrameworkCore - My core code, not to be exposed to clients
Framework1
Framework2
```

Dependencies are as follow:

```
Framework1 -> FrameworkCore
Framework2 -> Framework1
```

Note that some clients can include both Framework1 and Framework2 in their project.
I tried including all the dependencies in "Target Dependencies" and "Link Binaries With Library", but this mostly results in duplicate symbols.